# Webdriver - IE Flickering while taking the screenshot

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem of Flickering while taking the screenshot in IE, i have searched all over the internet and found no solution for this issue.

I have found this alternate solution for taking the screenshots for the test steps.

I have not used the webdriver API to take the screenshot but instead relied on Java Robot API to take the screenshot.

I have used the following code for taking the screenshots in IE without any flickering.

```
public static boolean TakeScreenshot(String filePath){
boolean b = false;
try {
    BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

    b = ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filePath));            

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return b;
```

}

is there any solution to the webdriver API for this flickering issue in Internet Explorer?

Comment: What do you mean with "flickering" and why is this a problem?

Comment: @oberlies - When screenshot is taken in IE running on slower machines, the IE window does a kind of minimize maximize action. As to why this is a problem - Sometimes because of the whole IE window does not get captured.

Comment: @lost exactly brother... i have seen this on machines which are of moderate hardware also, this happens only for IE not for any other browsers. this look like a pure IE problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised you did not find any references to this on the web. There is at least one [blog post](http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/13/are-your-ie-webdriver-tests-running-slow-maybe-its-the-screenshots/) that makes passing mention of it, and there's always the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/cpp/iedriver/CommandHandlers/ScreenshotCommandHandler.h) that would tell you exactly what it is doing.

The "flickering" you describe is probably due to the way the IE driver manipulates the IE window to take a screenshot. In the WebDriver API, a screenshot should be taken of the full DOM of a page. The IE driver uses the Windows [PrintWindow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to take the screenshot. However, the only way to take a screenshot of the entire DOM is to resize the IE browser window to display the entire DOM before taking the screenshot. The driver then restores the previous size of the window. This window resize is what appears to cause "flickering". Since the Firefox and Chrome drivers use fundamentally different ways to generate their screenshots (methods unavailable to the IE driver due to the latter's architecture), they do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: i have gone through that website, but they say that to mostly avoid taking screenshots for IE :)... thanks for taking time explaining the details... for my specific project i was able to solve with the code mentioned as the pages fit with in the browser...